# Признавать духовное родство за кем-л.?

Tags: управление, точное-словоупотребление

> Кумовство в Сербии чрезвычайно уважаемо и даже священно. Признаваемая
>   мистической, эта связь между людьми считается столь тесной, что даже
>   браки между семьями кумовьёв запрещены. Нами это уже позабытая форма
>   отношений, когда человек, а позже и его семья **признают духовное
>   родство за близким или уважаемым человеком** и нередко ставят его выше
>   кровного. Кум или кума получают невероятный почёт, к их словам
>   прислушиваются, на их помощь рассчитывают в первую очередь.

Помогите угадать, что было задумано, спасибо.

Comment: Нами — это кем? Кем позабыта... форма отношений?

Comment: Нами —  это россиянами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Для нас*** это уже позабытая форма отношений, когда человек, а позже и его семья признают **право на духовное родство** за близким или уважаемым человеком и нередко ставят его выше кровного.

ПРИЗНАТЬ, св. 1. что. Согласиться считать законным, действительным, существующим. П. чьи-л. права. **П. за кем-л. право, власть.**

Можно обойтись и без добавления ***права***, но это слово усиливает значимость духовного родства.

Примеры управления:

Труднее всего давалось смирение, когда был обязан **признать за родиной** ее историческую правоту.

Мы должны **признать за природой** ту же эстетическую и историческую ценность, которую мы **признаём за произведениями искусства** и памятниками истории

Comment: Шаронушка, спасибо за все ответы. Здесь меня смущает предлог *за*, почему не без него... Родство с кем-л.

Comment: Здесь, вероятно, глагол "признать" управляет двумя падежами: признать что-то за кем-то. Но: Состоять в родстве с кем-л. Вступить в р. с кем-л

Comment: А автор молчит. Я попросила паузу в чтении - ушла с головой в Инди-Кота, я сражаться люблю. И видимо, мой тайм-аут разрушил авторовы отношения с издательством, ведь без нашей совместной (стекэксчейнджевской) правки текст никому и не покажешь...